# Average colour of slic superpixel

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, superpixels

I want to segment an image using slic superpixels and then replace the original colour of a superpixel with the average colour of said superpixel.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage.segmentation import slic, mark_boundaries
from skimage.data import astronaut
from skimage.measure import regionprops

img = astronaut()
segments = slic(img, n_segments=512, compactness=10,
            multichannel=True,
            enforce_connectivity=True,
            convert2lab=True)
regions = regionprops(segments, intensity_image=img)
```

I get the error`ValueError: Label and intensity image must have thesame shape.`
Segments shape is (512,512) and img shape  in (512,512,3). What is the correct use of `regionprops` in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops), `regionprops` can only quantify a grey-value image, and won't work for color.

A simple solution would be to measure average intensity in each channel separately, and combine the results:

```
out = np.empty_like(img)
for ii in range(3):
   regions = regionprops(segments, intensity_image=img[:,:,ii])
   # paint, and write to out[:,:,ii]
```

Using [DIPlib](https://diplib.org) this can be done quite simply (disclaimer: I'm an author):

```
import diplib as dip

segments = segments.astype('uint32')  # 64-bit types not accepted by DIPlib
msr = dip.MeasurementTool.Measure(segments, img, ['Mean'])
out = dip.ObjectToMeasurement(segments, msr['Mean'])
out.Show()
```

[image: output of code above]

Answer (score 4):

I followed the first recommendation of the accepted answer. Working version of my code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.segmentation import slic
from skimage.data import astronaut
from skimage.measure import regionprops

def paint_region_with_avg_intensity(rp, mi, channel):
    for i in range(rp.shape[0]):
        img[rp[i][0]][rp[i][1]][channel] = mi

img = astronaut()
segments = slic(img, n_segments=512, compactness=10,
            multichannel=True,
            enforce_connectivity=True,
            convert2lab=True)

for i in range(3):
    regions = regionprops(segments, intensity_image=img[:,:,i])
    for r in regions:
        paint_region_with_avg_intensity(r.coords, int(r.mean_intensity), i)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image]